# ClassCastException while searching for LDAP user

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

After migrating to Spring security 4.2.2 (from 3.1), I am hitting the following error in LDAP user search:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx cannot be cast to org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
  at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:345)
  at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate$3.executeWithContext(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:318)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:817)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:803)
  at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:316)
  at org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:127)
  ...
  ...
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving the issue. I am using OpenLDAP server for the test if it makes any difference.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I had the same issue and manage to solve it somehow, so I thought I should share.

I'm using Spring Security 4.2.3 and I had something similar:

```java
public AdvisorResponse getAdvisorInfo(final String uid) {
    return cdsLdapTemplate.searchForObject(
            createCriteria(uid), this::mapAdvisorResponse
    );
}

private AdvisorResponse mapAdvisorResponse(final Object ctx) {
    final DirContextAdapter context = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
    final AdvisorResponse advisor = new AdvisorResponse();
    advisor.setUid(context.getStringAttribute("uid"));
    return advisor;
}

private ContainerCriteria createCriteria(final String uid) {
    return query()
            .base("ou=people")
            .countLimit(1)
            .searchScope(SUBTREE)
            .timeLimit(TIMEOUT)
            .where("uid").is(uid);
}
```

It used to work flawlessly until I had to run it in an @Async thread, then I started to have the same class cast exception.
As suggested [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/65712-getting-classcastexception-even-when-i-am-not-using-custom-dirobjectfactory) the error seems to be due to a different classloader used in the thread. My solution was to force the correct classloader into the execution thread:

```java
public AdvisorResponse getAdvisorInfo(final String uid) {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

    return cdsLdapTemplate.searchForObject(
            createCriteria(uid), this::mapAdvisorResponse
    );
}
```

Comment: In case of those who stumbled upon the dead link to the forum thread:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170112185420/http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/65712-getting-classcastexception-even-when-i-am-not-using-custom-dirobjectfactory